# Testing function that creates a list of DOM components

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which creates an Array of components.  Each component is an outer div with a few inner divs.

```
function createDivs(quizQuestions) {
    var returnElements = new Array();
    $.each(quizQuestions.questions, function(i, val){

    // create the div.
    quizDiv = $('<div class="questionContainer radius">')
    questionDiv = $('<div class="question"><b><span>QuestionText</span></b></div>');
    quizDiv.append(questionDiv);

    // Now change the question div text.
    questionDiv.text = val.question;
    answerDiv = $('<div class="answers">');
    // ...
    // ...
    // Now the answers.
    questionDiv.append(answerDiv);
    returnElements[i] = quizDiv;
});
return returnElements;
```

I pass JSON such as:

```
   {questions:[{"question":"Name the best Rugby team?",
   "answers":["Leinster", "Munster", "Ulster", "Connaught"],
   "correct_answer":"Leinster"},
   {"question":"Name the best DJ?",
   "answers":["Warren K", "Pressure", "Digweed", "Sasha"],
   "correct_answer":"Leinster"}]};
```

I'd like to write a simpe unit test so that I could test the array of div returned made sense

Any tips?

Also, are my better to return a DOM component or just text?  The latter would be easier to test.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you want `returnElements[i] = questionDiv;` to be `returnElements[i] = quizDiv;`

Comment: @Travis J Good spot. I have fixed it.

Comment: not sure exactly what you want to test...but from performance standpoint you could cut down a significant number of function calls by creating a single html string for each `quizDiv` in it's entirety, and could extend that to one string for all the content in the JSON, and make one append to DOM for all the new content. Appending to the DOM is the most expensive part of the whole operation

Comment: [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) is a very popular unit testing framework for JavaScript. Are you asking for unit test framework recommendations or advice on how to write the tests?

Comment: @charlietfl That's a good answer. I'll accept that.

Comment: @Ray Toai yeah Qunit and the String approach is a really way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to test but it is far more performant to create as much html in strings as you possibly can to reduce function calls. Also append is expensive so ultimately making one string for all the new content represented by the JSON will be the biggest performance gain.

In my opinion it also makes code more readable since fragments are in same order as the would be in html editor

Example(my preferece is creating an array of all the string fragments, concatenation also commonly used):

```
var newcontent = [];
$.each(quizQuestions.questions, function(i, val) {
    newcontent.push('<div class="questionContainer radius">');
    newcontent.push('<div class="question"><b><span>' + val.question + '< /span></b > < /div>');

    $.each(val.answers, function(idx, answer) {
        newcontent.push('<div class="answers">' + answer + '</div > ')
    })

    newcontent.push(' </div></div > ');
});
```

Then to add content to DOM:

```
$('#someDiv').append( newcontent.join(''));
```

disclaimer: Not fully checked for proper closing/nesting of tags.